# Removing characters from a matrix column name

Tags: r

I have a large data matrix with thousands of columns.

The names look like this `PID.ZYT6.0926.SM.5GIEM` however I would like them to look like `PID-ZYT6`
So sub the first `.` for `-` and remove the everything from second `.` on.

I have tried this:

```
MatrixName <- for (col in 1:ncol(MatrixName)){
    colnames(MatrixName)[col] <- sub(".0*", "", colnames(MatrixName)[col])
}
```

But this didn't work - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
colnames(df) = gsub("\\..*","", (sub("\\.", "-", colnames(df))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do

```r
gsub("^([^.]+)(\\.)([^.]+)(.+)", "\\1-\\3", "PID.ZYT6.0926.SM.5GIEM")
#R> "PID-ZYT6"
```

Thus, the call could be

```r
colnames(df) <- 
  gsub("^([^.]+)(\\.)([^.]+)(.+)", "\\1-\\3", colnames(df))
```